How to update a prop in another component?
I have a list in page.js and I need the contents of the list in another component which is loaded in page.js:
var accounts = [];
...
<div className="main">
    <LeftPanel accounts={accounts}/>
</div>

accounts is a list of the following objects:
{
    uid: some_uid,
    email: account_email
}

LeftPanel accepts accounts as a prop:
export default function LeftPanel({accounts}) {
...
<div>
   {accounts.map(account => (
       <p key={account.uid}>{account.email}</p>
   ))}
</div>
...
}

As accounts are retrieved a I do accounts.push to update accounts. I would like for LeftPanel to update the accounts. How can I update the list of accounts in LeftPanel as accounts is updated in page.js?
I thought using states for accounts and using setAccounts may solve the issue as they invoke a rerender, but it did not.

   const App = () => {
  const [accounts, setAccounts] = useState([{ email: "test", uid: 1 }]);

  const updateAccountData = () => {
    setAccounts((prev) => [...prev, { email: "test1", uid: 2 }]);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={updateAccountData}>Update data</button>
      <LeftPanel accounts={accounts} />
    </div>
  );
};

you can handle with state for updating the data

As I mentioned, I have tried and it did not work, unfortunately.

How you are updating an data can please provide an some exact code what did you want try, If it codesanbox means is good @Eshy

Maybe you can try adding key in LeftPanel components in page.js. So when there's a changes in accounts size, LeftPanel will re-render the component.
var accounts = [];
...
<div className="main">
    <LeftPanel key={accounts.length} accounts={accounts}/>
</div>

